# java.lang.AbstractMethodError - After upgrading Netty Jar from 4.0.48 to any 4.1.x jar

Tags: java, netty, apache-drill, abstractmethoderror

In my Apache Drill JDBC project, I was using `4.0.48.Final Netty` jar(s). And, It was working fine. Now, when I am upgrading from 4.0.48 to any of 4.1.x jar(say 4.1.50), while running the project it's throwing:

> Details:java.lang.AbstractMethodError:io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf.touch(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lio/netty/buffer/ByteBuf;

No additional stack trace is provided.

NOTE: Used Netty jars are..

- netty-buffer-4.1.50.Final netty-codec-4.1.50.Final
- netty-common-4.1.50.Final netty-handler-4.1.50.Final
- netty-transport-4.1.50.Final netty-resolver-4.1.50.Final (It is not required with 4.0.48)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT-1 : I am using below jars in my classpath

antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar

commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar

commons-logging-1.2.jar

commons-codec-1.10.jar

protobuf-java-3.6.1.jar

jackson-annotations-2.10.1.jar

jackson-core-2.10.1.jar

jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar

jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar

jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar

javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar

joda-time-2.9.9.jar

log4j-1.2.17.jar

metrics-core-4.0.2.jar

metrics-jvm-4.0.2.jar

reflections-0.9.10.jar

slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar

config-1.2.1.jar

zookeeper-3.4.11.jar

hadoop-common-3.2.1.jar

hadoop-auth-3.2.1.jar

drill-common-1.17.0.jar

drill-hive-exec-shaded-1.17.0.jar

drill-java-exec-1.17.0.jar

drill-logical-1.17.0.jar

drill-memory-base-1.17.0.jar

drill-protocol-1.17.0.jar

drill-rpc-1.17.0.jar

vector-1.17.0.jar

drill-shaded-guava-23.0.jar

junit-4.12.jar

hppc-0.7.1.jar

commons-collections-3.2.2.jar

commons-configuration-1.6.jar

metrics-jmx-4.0.2.jar

commons-configuration2-2.1.1.jar

stax2-api-3.1.4.jar

woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar

guava-29.0-jre.jar

curator-client-4.3.0.jar

curator-framework-4.3.0.jar

curator-recipes-4.3.0.jar

curator-x-discovery-4.3.0.jar

netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar

netty-resolver-4.1.50.Final.jar

netty-handler-4.1.50.Final.jar

netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar

netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar

netty-buffer-4.1.50.Final.jar

Comment: What is the stacktrace of that error? It sounds like your code (or one of your dependencies) is relying on a specific method in Netty that has been removed in the later version.

Comment: Actually, there is no stacktrace. I am only getting  this error -"java.lang.AbstractMethodError: io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf.touch(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lio/netty/buffer/ByteBuf;
"

Comment: An `AbstractMethodError` has a stacktrace, but likely how you are logging it doesn't include it. In any case, verify your dependencies and check which version of Netty they require. And contrary to my previous comment: it is possible the issue is one of pulling in multiple versions of Netty.

Comment: Are you sure you not have multiple different versions of netty on the class path ?

Comment: Yes, I don't have multiple version of Netty in my classpath. To ensure this I removed all the Netty jars and used all-in-one too.

Comment: Please, have a look of list of jars that I am using.